# Return the value by given addresses

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hint to my query.

[image]

On row 4 there are cell-addresses referring to some data.

How can I write a code by using these info to extract the value from the respective cells?

Comment: Needs more context - please add example inputs and expected outputs.  A good start would be to look into using `Application.Match`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please. It will return in Immediate Window the respective cells value. The code assumes that "R34C54" means Row 34 and column 54...

```
Sub ReturnValueFromR1C1Label()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, iRow As Long, iCol As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long, i As Long
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
    lastCol = sh.Cells(4, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
     For i = 3 To lastCol
        iRow = Split(Split(sh.Cells(4, i).Value, "R")(1), "C")(0)
        iCol = Split(sh.Cells(4, i).Value, "C")(1)
        Debug.Print Cells(iRow, iCol).Address & " value = " & Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

To see the returned values, use `Ctrl + G` being in VBE...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I get the idea from it. Appreciate all!

Comment: @user13954304: Glad I could help! But, should I understand that the above code did not answer your question? Otherwise, we here tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else looking for something similar will know that it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Formula` property of `Range`, something like:

```
Cells(2, 1).Formula = "=" & Cells(1, 1)
```

where `Cells(1,1)` contains the address, such as `R10C12`.

The `.Value` of `Cells(2, 1)` is now the contents of `R10C12`.